# (Done) Reopen: Fired, accused of conducting web searches I didn't do

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Fired, accused of conducting web searches I didn't do.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125553/fired-accused-of-conducting-web-searches-i-didnt-do)

This is not about a company specific policy.  This is general enough to where it is easily answerable, and has two VERY good answers

[HERE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125553/fired-accused-of-conducting-web-searches-i-didnt-do/125573#125573)

and

[HERE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125553/fired-accused-of-conducting-web-searches-i-didnt-do/125556#125556)

The employee was fired for searches done on his computer, that could happen at literally any company.

The answers about standard security and protecting your machine are excellent and the question should be reopened.  Perhaps it should be edited a bit, but it should be open.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Seems completely on-topic to me.

Comment: Don't see why it was closed in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Reopened.

It seems fairly general to me and isn't tied to a specific company's regulations.